# lightning:datatable disable hover

Tags: lightning-datatable, mousehover

I created a lightning:datatable, and I want to disable the "hover", I add the "slds-no-row-hover" class, but it doesn't work.. here is my code..[image]

```
<lightning:datatable aura:id="tablaVariacionesCheques" id="tablaVariacionesCheques1" 
                                                            data="{!v.datosVariaciones}" 
                                                            columns="{!v.columnasVariaciones}" 
                                                            keyField="idRegistro"  
                                                            hideCheckboxColumn="true" 
                                                            resizeColumnDisabled="true" 
                                                            onrowaction="{}" 
                                                            class="slds-table--bordered slds-table--col-bordered slds-no-row-hover"
                                                            suppressBottomBar="false"
                                                            oncellchange=""
                                                            showRowNumberColumn="false"
                                                            onheaderaction=""/>
```

Comment: Hi Kevin, please [edit] your question to post code *inline as text* and use the `{}` button to ensure it's formatted correctly. Thanks! Images aren't usable for people with screen readers and are tough on mobile.

Comment: Hi David, 
I just edited it

Comment: Did you get any solution on this?